# How to extract the bottom layer voxels using open3d?

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I want to extract the bottom layer voxels. For example, extract the part from the armadillo. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

This is how I find the lowest voxel.

```
#Get voxels center coordinate
def get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel_grid):
    voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
    voxel_center = []
    
    for voxel in voxels:
        voxel_center.append(voxel_grid.get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel.grid_index))
    
    return voxel_center

#Find lowest voxels index
def find_lowest_voxel_index(voxel_grid):
    voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
    voxel_center = get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel_grid)
    
    for i in range(0, len(voxel_center)):
        if i == 0:
            min_z = voxel_center[i, 2]
        else:
            if min_z > voxel_center[i, 2]:
                min_z = voxel_center[i, 2]
    ind = 0
    lowest_voxel_index = []
    
    for center in voxel_center:
        if center[2] == min_z:
            print(center[2])
            lowest_voxel_index.append(voxels[ind].grid_index)
            ind += 1
    
    return lowest_voxel_index
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can get the voxels through `.get_voxels()` and filter them based on their `z` coordinate (assuming that the _bottom_ has the smallest `z`).

Comment: @DilaraGokay I've filtered them base on the z coordinate, but how to extract those voxels to create a new voxel grid. Can it be done through `grid_index`?

Comment: @KevinLiu thanks for the follow-up, but it is hard to pinpoint what you should do without exactly knowing what you have in your existing solution. Could you please edit your question and add a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates how you filter the coordinates and so on? By doing this, we can understand the question easier and you can get an answer faster&to-the-point.

Comment: @DilaraGokay thanks for reply. This is how I find lowest voxel. Is it able to extract those voxel and using them to make a new voxel grid?

Comment: @KevinLiu I addressed a few things about finding the voxels. Regarding the extraction, I do not know much about this either. I am not 100% sure if this would work, but you might consider using `create_from_triangle_mesh_within_bounds`. After finding the lowest z, you can use this value to determine the z-axis of `max_bound` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. I'll point out a few things that you should change and then a way to verify the solution.

### Solution

Things that should change in the given solution:

1. You cannot access the z-axis through `voxel_center[i, 2]` since `voxel_center` is a list, not a numpy array. You should instead access them as  `voxel_center[i][2]`.
2. You should increment `ind` at each loop, not only when the condition is true. Alternatively, you can use `enumerate` which overcomes this cleanly.

Therefore, the correct implementation would be the following:

```py
#Get voxels center coordinate
def get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel_grid):
    voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
    voxel_center = []
    
    for voxel in voxels:
        voxel_center.append(voxel_grid.get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel.grid_index))
    
    return voxel_center

#Find lowest voxels index
def find_lowest_voxel_index(voxel_grid):
    voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
    voxel_center = get_voxel_center_coordinate(voxel_grid)
    
    for i in range(0, len(voxel_center)):
        if i == 0:
            min_z = voxel_center[i][2]
        else:
            if min_z > voxel_center[i][2]:
                min_z = voxel_center[i][2]
    ind = 0
    lowest_voxel_index = []
    
    for center in voxel_center:
        if center[2] == min_z:
            print(center[2])
            lowest_voxel_index.append(voxels[ind].grid_index)
        ind += 1
    
    return lowest_voxel_index
```

### Verification

To verify the solution, you might want to visualize the results. However, `VoxelGrid` does not have any method that allows the user to e.g., change the color of a particular voxel. Therefore, you can think of creating extra meshes to visualize the filtered voxels. Since `VoxelGrid` provides `get_voxel_bounding_points`, you can make use of these points to create an `AxisAlignedBoundingBox`.

```py
lowest_index = find_lowest_voxel_index(voxel_grid)  # this uses your solution after modifications

bounding_box = []
for i in lowest_index:
    bb = o3d.geometry.AxisAlignedBoundingBox.create_from_points(voxel_grid.get_voxel_bounding_points(i))
    bb.color = np.array([1,0,1])  # feel free to choose any other color
    bounding_box.append(bb)


axes = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(origin=np.array([100,100,100]), size=100)  # in order to be sure of the direction

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid, *bounding_box, axes])
```

This is how running this code on an armadillo mesh looks like. Note that I added the coordinate frame to make sure of the direction. Blue arrow points toward +z. The voxel with the lowest z value has purple edges.
[image]